# Как получить номера всех домов на улице с помощью python?

Tags: python, google-maps, поиск-api, яндекс-карты

Есть страна, город, улица и надо на этой улице получить номера всех домов. Это возможно? Если да то как?

Comment: Придется изучать возможности API картографических сервисов. У Яндекса есть "Геокордер", на официальном сайте можно изучить документацию, возможно, что-то найдете

Comment: Этот сайт - не поисковик. здесь помогают решать конкретные задачи. google вам в помощь.

Comment: @strawdog я пол гугла посмотрел, ничего нашёл